# How to Read Specific data from to InputStream object?

Tags: java, android

How to read Specific data from InputStream object, While i am using HttpUrlConnection object to make connection. I want to READ and POST data ,for example , i want to read specific Tag data , like  and so on. like wise i want to Post also.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("some URL ...")
            .openConnection();

    // reading data from connection
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    System.out.println(readStream(in));

}
private static String readStream(InputStream is) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      int i = is.read();
      while(i != -1) {
        bo.write(i);
        i = is.read();
      }
      return bo.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return "";
    }
}
```

}

please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I was getting JSONObject in my case :

```
static InputStream is = null;


            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }

                is.close();

                json = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: i asked, How to get specific data? in my Question i m able to get full HTML. I want to access <Tag> value data by name/id.

Comment: convert your in into string, as i have answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use jsoup http://jsoup.org
It's got tools to handle all u wanna do with the html.